# Help with crontab

Tags: cron

I have this simple bash script for pinging my home server. In crontab I configured it to run every 2am. Then email me the ping result.

The strange thing is, it always runs every minute no matter what I configure in my crontab. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
0 2 * * * pinger.sh
```

The Script

```
#!/bin/sh
masterip="192.168.2.1"
pname="Home Server"
sender="From: Server Monitoring <myemail@gmail.com>"
subject="$pname Server Connectivity"
mail="myemail@gmail.com"

ping -c1 $masterip
if [ "$?" = 0 ];
  then
    pingmessage="$pname is reachable via LAN IP $masterip"
    pingms=$(ping -c 1 $masterip | sed -ne '/.*time=/{;s///;s/\..*//;p;}')
  else
    pingmessage="$pname is unreachable via LAN IP $masterip"
    pingms=$(ping -c 1 $masterip | sed -ne '/.*time=/{;s///;s/\..*//;p;}')
fi

{
echo "$pingmessage"
echo "with $pingms ms ping"
} | mail -a "$sender" -s "$subject" $mail
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but there are quotes missing in the assignment `pname=Home Server`.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. You are right. there are quotes in the scripts. I must have removed then when i was posting this.

Comment: Also, do you have many instances of your script file lying around? You don't give the full path to the script in your crontab schedule, so you may not run the copy of the script that you think you're running. Correct this by using e.g. `"$HOME/pinger.sh"` in the crontab.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm running the correct script. Because when I rename the file the emails stop. I hate a custom path on the crontab
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/etc/scripts

Comment: "hate" or "have"?

Comment: Substitute a simpler script `date >> myCron.log`, tail that, and get the crontab under control first. NB: cron does NOT read your profiles: the default cron path is `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin`

Comment: How did you add the command to cron? (Specifically, did you use `crontab`, or did you edit a file under either `/etc` or `/var`)? Does `crontab -l` report the correct invocation?

Comment: I used crontab -e

Answer (score 1):

If you append a redirection to your command in crontab

```
"Command >> /path/to/log 2>&1"
```

Output will be visible.

Remember Cron hasn't got your environment, so your command path should start from root `/path/to/command` and commands in your script unless you setup the PATH environment variable to your required search path.

Comment: Hi I have the file path in my crontab -e
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/etc/scripts

Comment: Great, so what what does the log say (Update your question with output), maybe the log should use the append syntax (Ive updated the answer).